# Coding a new variable in R based on a field values of both categorical and numerical data

Tags: r, if-statement

So sorry to bother you but I am trying to classify a new variable named CODE based on the values of a field named time, this comes from a machine that records how much time in hours a pipe is under control
this is the data

```
df<- tibble::tribble(
~time,
"5",
"4",
"NO_TIME",
"7",
"23",
"34",
"87",
"NO_TIME",
"98")
```

this is my code:

```
df %>% 
mutate(CODE=ifelse(time<1,"MENOR_1",
                    ifelse(time>=1 & time<6, "2_6_horas",
                           ifelse(time>=6 & time<12, "6_12_horas",
                                  ifelse(time=="NULL", "NO_REG",
                                         ifelse(time>=12, "MAS_DE_12","ERROR"))))))
```

but the output is just not realistic

```
A tibble: 9 x 2
  time    CODE     
  <chr>   <chr>    
1 5       ALERT    
2 4       A        
3 NO_TIME NO_RECORD
4 7       ALERT    
5 23      A        
6 34      A        
7 87      ALERT    
8 NO_TIME NO_RECORD
9 98      ALERT
```

am I doing something wrong? or is it because the data set has both numerical and categorical data? thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison operators should be on the `numeric` converted column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     # // create a new column by converting to numeric
     # // character elements will be converted to NA
     mutate(time1 = as.numeric(time),
            # // use case_when instead of nested ifelse
            CODE = case_when(
                   time1 < 1 ~ 'MENOR_1', 
                   between(time1, 1, 6) ~ '2_6_horas',
                   between(time1, 6, 12) ~ '6_12_horas',
                   time1 >=12 ~ 'MAS_DE_12',
                   time == 'NULL' ~ 'NO_REG',
                   TRUE ~ 'ERROR'), time1 = NULL)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
#  time    CODE      
#  <chr>   <chr>     
#1 5       2_6_horas 
#2 4       2_6_horas 
#3 NO_TIME ERROR     
#4 7       6_12_horas
#5 23      MAS_DE_12 
#6 34      MAS_DE_12 
#7 87      MAS_DE_12 
#8 NO_TIME ERROR     
#9 98      MAS_DE_12
```

---

This could be also simplified with `cut` or `findInterval` by specifying the `breaks` and `labels`

```
df %>%
  mutate(time1 = as.numeric(time), CODE = cut(time1, 
            breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 6, 12, Inf), 
            labels = c('MENOR_1', '2_6_horas', '6_12_horas', 'MAS_DE_12')), 
      CODE = case_when(time == 'NO_TIME' ~ 'ERROR',
        time == 'NULL' ~ 'NO_REG', TRUE ~ as.character(CODE)))
```